# Selenium multiple select by option text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a form which contains a multiple `select` where I want to select and click on an `option` tag by it's text. For example I might want to select the option that says `Option 2` and click on it. How might I do this?

Here's the code:

```
<select name="model" required="" id="id_model" multiple="">
  <option value="31">Option 1</option>

  <option value="20">Option 2</option>

  <option value="25">Option 3</option>

  <option value="29">Option 4</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can handle it by using `Select`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('id_model'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Option 2')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value("20")

# select by index
select.select_by_index(1)
```